# Commas inside the password while using "mount"

Tags: linux, mount, samba

Need to mount a specific directory from Windows to `Linux`:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=somebody password=12,34 //192.168.1.3/share /mnt/server
```

Notice that there is a comma inside the password, and that makes `Shell` mistake it as a separator.

How to deal with that situation?

Thanks!

Comment: try escaping the comma using "\" or "" character, I think it should work

Comment: It still didn't work while adding a "\"......

Answer (score 5):

Description of `password` option in [man mount.cifs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) explicitely says, that you cannot use comma-contained password in command line:

> Note that a password which contains the delimiter character (i.e. a comma ',') will fail to be parsed correctly on the command line. However, the same password defined in the PASSWD environment variable or via a credentials file (see below) or entered at the password prompt will be read correctly.

You may set PASSWD variable within same line as `mount`:

```
PASSWD=12,34 mount -t cifs -o username=somebody //192.168.1.3/share /mnt/server
```

Alternatively you may use credentials file, as described in this manual.

---

BTW, it is not *shell* who incorrectly interprets comma. Actually, `username` and `password` are both *suboptions* for `-o` option, and these suboptions should be delimited by comma for being correctly parsed by the *program*(mount) itself:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=<username>,password=<password> ...
```

And such *suboption* mechanism have no means to parse comma inside suboption's value.